# prevent page repositioning after editing with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm updating several image src attributes on a page, and they are updated properly, but when jQuery updates those items, the page scrolls down to those items (they are below the 'fold') - how can I stop the page from auto-scrolling down to the changes I'm making with jQuery?  I see the same behavior with IE and FireFox

```
// insert images into current page 
$("img.nominphoto",$(".nominwrap")).each(function(){    
  var userItemID=$(this).attr("title");
    $(this).attr("src",hashImageURLs[userItemID]);
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to fines it by using `$(window).scrollTop` and maybe hooking to the image's load method using `.one()` so it only triggers then releases (reset scrollTop when it's completed loading)--but this is a hack at best.

If you're not already (and assuming the images are fixed-height and width) it's "proper" to specify the width/height of an image. This allows the renderer to layout the page (despite missing or updated content), but also prevents any image(s) [re]loading from having adverse effects later on.

Comment: After a couple more hours of looking at this it turned out the cause of the repositioning was not me changing the graphics, but actually an input box near the bottom of the page that received the focus.  Sorry for the false alarm.  Thanks for the help.